# Sort by external data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having quite a struggle with a query and don't know if what I want is possible or not.

In short I would need to sort the results based on external data, this external data I am using to search within a range of id's(1):

```
{  
   "from":0,
   "size":30,
   "query":{  
      "function_score":{  
         "functions":[  
            {  
               "weight":2,
               "filter":{  
                  "bool":{  
                     "must":[  
                        {  
                           "query":{  
                              "match_all":{  

                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "query":{  
            "filtered":{  
               "query":{  
                  "bool":{  
                     "must":[  
                        {  
                           "match":{  
                              "validated":true
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "id": [   //<--- search within given id range
                               "id1",
                               "id2",
                               ....
                               "id3"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "filter":{  
                  "or":{  
                     "filters":[  
                        {  
                           "and":{  
                              "filters":[  
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "_type":"type1"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                        ... //allot more
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "score_mode":"sum",
         "boost_mode":"replace"
      }
   },
   "min_score":1.5
}
```

*Story: Imagine you have multiple documents and 1 which is used for favorites feature (but it only stores the id, creation date and updated date).
A user searches within his favorites list and he should get the results in chronological order.*

(1) I search within a range of id's (limit to 1024 by default) in documents because I do not want to change the indexation (augment data), it would become a heavy process(allot of fields). **I would like to sort based on the creation date of these external id's**. This indexation is triggered async (server side) when a user visits various pages.

**Based on this, is it possible to sort the documents by external data?**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution (At least it works). I added each id with the weight of a timestamp score to get the recent first as follows:

```
{  
   "from":0,
   "size":30,
   "query":{  
      "function_score":{  
         "functions":[  
            {  
               {
                  "filter":{
                      "term":{
                          "id"=>"id1"
                      }
                  },
                  "weight"=> "timestamp_score" // timestamp divided by 10000000., ex: 14.065543
               }
            }
         ],
         "query":{  
            "filtered":{  
               "query":{  
                  "bool":{  
                     "must":[  
                        {  
                           "match":{  
                              "validated":true
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "id": [   //<--- search within given id range
                               "id1",
                               "id2",
                               ....
                               "id3"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "filter":{  
                  "or":{  
                     "filters":[  
                        {  
                           "and":{  
                              "filters":[  
                                 {  
                                    "term":{  
                                       "_type":"type1"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                        ... //allot more
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "score_mode":"sum",
         "boost_mode":"replace"
      }
   },
   "min_score":1.5
}
```

This works fine even with **1024** id's (my current max limit), it affects the statement not overall (max **1024** filter statements, max **1024** score boosts statements).

Any other ideas are wellcome, seems a bit hacky to me somehow